# Ruby чтение RSS Страница не найдена

Tags: ruby, rss

Пытаюсь прочитать страницу с данными RSS. С одного адреса нормально читает, с другого - ошибка 404.
Вот это отрабатывает без проблем:

```
uri = URI.parse("http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/feeds/news.rss")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host)
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path)
res = http.request(req)
puts res.body
```

А такой URL выдает ошибку 404 (и возвращает html - страница не найдена):
http://zakupki.gov.ru/epz/order/quicksearch/rss

Хотя ссылка рабочая, в браузере нормально показывает ленту.

Подозреваю, что это может быть из-за отсутствия ссылки на конкретный файл rss в строке запроса. Сначала пробовал использовать RSS::Parser.parse и получил ошибку 404, поэтому решил попробовать через Net, но проблема ровно та же.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Там скорее всего фильтр на юзер-агента стоит.
Добавьте в запрос хидер с указанием юзер-агента реального браузера и должно все получиться.

Например такое работает,

```
curl -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.89 Safari/537.36" http://zakupki.gov.ru/epz/order/quicksearch/rss
```

В руби сами сконвертите, надеюсь.

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно, получилось.